# Como filtro los registros repetidos con Entity Framewok

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

necesito ayuda.
Tengo una tabla "expediente" y otra "usuario", por regla de negocio necesito ir trasladando los expedientes entre usuarios, para ello tengo la tabla llamada "traslado". El problema que tengo es que un expediente puede ser trasladado varias veces al mismo usuario, obviamente en fechas diferentes y lo que necesito es ponerle al usuario en su bandeja de entrada, todos los expedientes que se le asignan y para los expedientes re-asignados tomar el traslado con la fecha mas reciente. Este es mi código que me devuelve todos los expedientes, incluidos los repetidos.

```
 [HttpGet("[action]/{idusuario}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ExpedienteViewModel>> ListarporUsuarioTras([FromRoute] int idusuario)
    {
        var traslado = await _context.Traslados
            .Include(e => e.expediente.titular)
            .Include(e => e.expediente.regente)
            .Include(e => e.expediente.tipoexpediente)
            .Include(e => e.expediente.usuario.regional)
            .Include(e => e.expediente.regente)
            .Where(e => e.idusuario == idusuario)
            .OrderBy(e => e.expediente.titular.nombre)

            .ToListAsync();

        return traslado.Select(e => new ExpedienteViewModel
        {
            idexpediente = e.idexpediente,
            num_expediente = e.expediente.num_expediente,
            idtitular = e.expediente.idtitular,
            nombre_titular = e.expediente.titular.nombre,
            representante = e.expediente.representante,
            idregente = e.expediente.idregente,
            nombre_regente = e.expediente.regente.nombre,
            idtipo_expediente = e.expediente.idtipo_expediente,
            nombre_tipoexpediente = e.expediente.tipoexpediente.nombre,
            modalidad_inab = e.expediente.modalidad_inab,
            anio_inicio = e.expediente.anio_inicio,
            anio_fin = e.expediente.anio_fin,
            idarea_protegida = e.expediente.idarea_protegida,
            idzona_demanejo_ap = e.expediente.idzona_demanejo_ap,
            idusuario = e.expediente.idusuario,
            nombre_usuario = e.expediente.usuario.nombre,
            idregional = e.expediente.idregional,
            idmunicipio = e.expediente.idmunicipio,
            nombre_um_finca = e.expediente.nombre_um_finca,
            nombre_proyecto = e.expediente.nombre_proyecto,
            tipo_documento_propiedad = e.expediente.tipo_documento_propiedad,
            num_documento_propiedad = e.expediente.num_documento_propiedad,
            direccion_um = e.expediente.direccion_um,
            asunto = e.expediente.asunto,                
            fecha_traslado = e.fecha_traslado.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            area_total = e.expediente.area_total,
            area_proyecto = e.expediente.area_proyecto,
            area_proteccion = e.expediente.area_proteccion,
            estado = e.expediente.estado,
            iddepartamento = e.expediente.iddepartamento
        }); ; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias aplicar un `group by` por el `idexpediente` para unir todos los expedientes que se transladaron

```
var traslados = await (from e in_context.Traslados
                        where e.idusuario == idusuario
                    group e by e.idexpediente into g
                    select new ExpedienteViewModel()
                    {
                        idexpediente = g.Key,
                        num_expediente = g.First().expediente.num_expediente,

                        //resto propiedades

                        fecha_traslado = g.Max(x=> x.fecha_traslado).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),

                    }).ToListAsync();

return traslados;
```

Entendi que el id o key de la entidad `Traslados` no es el `idexpediente` por eso si se puede repetir lo agrupas

Ademas no necesitas los `Include()` sino vas a retornar la entidad `Translado` directamente, la estas conviertiendo en otra ViewModel por eso los include no hacen falta

En la agrupacion puedes aplicar el `Max()` para obtener la ultima fecha registrada en un translado

[Agrupar los resultados de consultas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Comment: Me devuelve error. InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'First<Traslado>(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: t.idexpediente,